# upgrade Visual Studio installation from "Just for me" to "Everyone"

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I'm using Visual Studio installation kit to create msi for my product.
I found a problem - I've installed the product in the past with "Just For Me" option, and now I would like to upgrade & change it to "Everyone".
At the end of the upgrade I can see two lines with my product at the "Add / Remove programs".
Does anyone has an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add Visual Studio to the question title please?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the only difference between "Just Me" and "Everyone" is the location of the shortcuts that are created.

If you right-click on your start-button and choose "Explore" you should be able to drag the "Visual Studio" program group from your user start menu folder to the all users start menu.

(Not on Windows atm so I can't give precise directions I'm afraid!).

Answer (score 0):

Each installation is unique for "everyone" and "Just me" option. You may need to uninstall the older version first to resolve this problem. There is no auto upgrade of the existing installation available.

If you had mentioned the version number in earlier installer. Then you can choose to use remove the earlier version by setting "**RemovePreviousVersion**" property to "**true**" in your new version.